# Encountered a compilation error with gcc 13.2

Tags: gcc

While trying to build a downloaded program, I've encountered a strange compilation error
with gcc 13.2 (built for mingw but I doubt that is significant). It can be reproduced with
the following code snippet

```
int gk_getopt(int __arg1, char *__arg2, char *__shortopts);

int main() {
    gk_getopt(23, "abc", "opts");
}

int gk_getopt(int a, int *b, char *c) {
}
```

The error messages from gcc are

```
metis_gcc13_compilation error_test.c:10:5: error: conflicting types for 'gk_getopt'; have 'int(int,  int *, char *)'
   10 | int gk_getopt(int a, int *b, char *c) {
      |     ^~~~~~~~~
metis_gcc13_compilation error_test.c:4:5: note: previous declaration of 'gk_getopt' with type 'int(int,  char *, char *)'
    4 | int gk_getopt(int __arg1, char *__arg2, char *__shortopts);
      |     ^~~~~~~~~
```

Comment: What compilation error? What is clear? Why is it clear? Why is the error strange, what is strange in it? If it can be reproduced with this code snippet, what is the result when it is reproduced? Please post the exact full verbatim output from the compiler. Please post the error message. What does the error message say?

Comment: It seems clear the problem is a due to the conflicting types.

Comment: `char *` is not `int *`.

Comment: Yes, many thanks to all who quickly replied to this! I was in such a hurry to create a simple test to reproduce my original problem that I didn't look closely enough to see that my new error was NOT the same as my original error! My apologies to all!

Comment: As far as the `__` goes, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71360576/the-meaning-of-and-in-clang-variables-and-functions.  Not the issue here obviously, but might be what caused your original issue.